# check if file exists bash not working

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, boolean

I would like to check if a file has been created and deposited on a specific directory that has been attached via SaMBa to a Linux machine. Based on the date, it should check if a file with a date in the name is there. I first create what "ls" should look for, then I do an if-else statement. Am I missing something or is my code wrong? Using /bin/env bash. Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
YESTERDAY=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "yesterday"`
#YESTERDAY="test"
LOCATION="/some/directory/some/other/directory"
FILENAME="$LOCATION/*MEMB*$YESTERDAY*"

echo "Filename is $FILENAME"
if [ -e "$FILENAME" ]
then
     echo "Found \"$FILENAME\" files from yesterday. WILL NOT SEND EMAIL."
else
     echo "FILE FROM YESTERDAY \"$FILENAME\" NOT FOUND"
fi
```

It never hits the "true" statement at all, even if there are files in the directory from yesterday, and the "else" executes all the time. If I change "YESTERDAY" to "2015-02-09" (today) or any other value that is true, it won't hit the true statement either.

I try the literal directory without a variable in the -e check and it works. 
About the only other time I can get the if construct to work is if I set "filename" to a file in the same directory of the script. Is it ignoring the slashes in the -e test? Please offer alternate ways, too.

In case there's an alternative, I know the following scripting: C++, Perl, beginning-to-intermediate bash scripting, PHP, and JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, all-caps names are reserved for environment variables and shell builtins; using them for variables local to your script risks namespace collisions.

Comment: Also, BashFAQ #4 is on-point for this question: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FILENAME="$LOCATION/*MEMB*$YESTERDAY*"
[ -e "$FILENAME" ]
```

...is looking for a filename with literal `*` characters in its name, not for whether any files match the pattern given.

The solution which might look obvious to some people, using `[ -e $FILENAME ]` without the quotes, doesn't work either -- since it evaluates to `[ -e ]` if there are zero results and `nullglob` is set (this is equivalent to `[ -n -e ]`, and evaluates as true!), and to an invalid `test` command line if more than one file matches the glob, which results in an error and a false result.

Instead, load the list of matching files into an array, and check its length (and, if you haven't run `shopt -s nullglob`, also check that the first element of the array exists):

```
# Important: Double-quote the parameter expansions, but NOT the globs!
filenames=( "$LOCATION"/*MEMB*"$YESTERDAY"* )
if (( ${#filenames[@]} )) && [[ -e ${filenames[0]} ]]; then
  echo "At least one file matches the name" >&2
else
  echo "No files exist" >&2
fi
```

The extra complexity here is because, by default, a glob expression with no matches expands to itself, so you can get a single name returned -- the unexpanded glob expression. You can tell the shell not to do that with the `nullglob` option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
filenames=( "$LOCATION"/*MEMB*"$YESTERDAY"* )
if (( ${#filenames[@]} )); then
  echo "At least one file matches the name" >&2
else
  echo "No files exist" >&2
fi
```

---

By the way, if your shell is POSIX sh rather than bash, then you may want to avoid needing to use arrays. You can do this by defining a function (to have its own argument list, so you aren't overwriting the global one), and then using the argument vector to hold your matching filenames:

```
check_for_filenames() {
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ -e "$1" ]; then
    echo "At least one file matches the name" >&2
    return 0
  else
    echo "No files match" >&2
    return 1
  fi
}
check_for_filenames "$LOCATION"/*MEMB*"$YESTERDAY"*
```

Comment: Is `$` a typo in `filenames=( "$LOCATION"/*"$MEMB"*"$YESTERDAY"* )` ?

Comment: @user3439894, Yes -- on my first pass, I read that as another variable being expanded. I tried to go back and fix those, but apparently missed an instance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you, I think I will try that. My alternative is Perl.

Answer (score -1):

Following your suggestions, I ended up putting the ls command's results into a variable, then that variable's contents into a file. While reading each line in the file, seeing if it matched "yesterday" pattern, then turning a flag on if so, to check and send email. I ended up having this:

```
# LET'S SAVE TODAY'S DATE FROM YESTERDAY
yesterday=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "yesterday"`
foundMEMB="no"

location="/some/directory/location"
echo "RESULTS in /some/directory/location" > empty.log
filename=$location/*$yesterday*
results=`ls $location/MEMB$yesterday*`
echo "$results" >> empty.log
for i in $( cat empty.log ) ; do
    #echo item: $i "is good"
    if [[ "$i" =~ "$yesterday" ]]; then
            echo "$i matches $yesterday"
            foundMEMB="yes"
    fi
done
if [[ "$foundMEMB" == "no" ]]; then
    mail -s "Found no MEMB file from date $yesterday." email_atsymbol_domain < empty.log
fi
echo "END"
exit $?
```

So that worked well because now I can see what was done if I ever look at empty.log and before, I couldn't. I am still learning so I was more comfortable like that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The Bash-idiomatic way is `for i in "$location/MEMB$yesterday"* ; do`; [ls should not be parsed](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [`for` should not be used to read lines](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).